# jQuery Click Event triggering only once

Tags: jquery

For some reason, I can only get the click event to fire once on the temperature element (id: #temp). After it converts to Fahrenheit, it doesn't convert back to Celsius. I just started with jQuery, so any help would be much appreciated. Source Code is below.

HTML Source:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Local Weather Code Camp Project</h1>
    <h4>Location</h4>
    <p id="location"></p>
    <h4>Weather</h4>
    <p id="weather"></p>
    <img id="icon">
    <h3 id="temp"></h3>
    <p id="check"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

jQuery Source:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
   $.getJSON('https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=' + position.coords.latitude + '&lon=' + position.coords.longitude , function(data){
     var tmpInt = 0;
     $("h1").html(JSON.stringify(data));
     $("#location").html(data.name);
     $("#weather").html(data.weather[0].description);
     $("#icon").attr("src", data.weather[0].icon);
     $("#temp").html(data.main.temp + "&#176; C");
     $(document).on('click','#temp',function() {
       tmpInt = data.main.temp;
       tmpInt = tmpInt * 1.8 +32;
       if("#temp:contains('&#176; C')") {
          $("#temp").html(tmpInt + "&#176; F");
          $("#check").html("Contains C");
       }
       else if("#temp:contains('&#176; F')") {
         $("#temp").html(data.main.temp + "&#176; C");
         $("#check").html("Contains F");
       }
     });
   });
 });
});
```

Working CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/michaelcmelton/pen/yoKeEW).

Comment: I suggest you look **very carefully** at `if("#temp:contains('&#176; C')")`. What exactly do you think that is evaluating?

Comment: In addition to the @Phil 's comment. Your click event is raised and your function is being called. I tried on your CodePen example, just put a simple `alert` . So your problem is not the one you stated.

Comment: @Phil I'd think it evaluates wether or not the given element contains that string, and if not moves to the next if or exits, correct?

Comment: You are missing something vitally important; you are only evaluating a string, not an element. You probably meant `if($("#temp:contains('&#176; C')").length)` but even then, jQuery's `:contains` selector evaluates text, not markup so it should be `:contains('° C')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition is always evaluating to true so the the temp is always changed to F.

Using another variable to remember what unit (C or F) is displayed works...

```
    var units = 'C';

    $("#temp").on("click", function() {
      tmpInt = data.main.temp;
      tmpInt = tmpInt * 1.8 + 32;

      if (units == 'C') {
        $("#temp").html(tmpInt + "&#176; F");
        units = 'F';
      } else if (units == 'F') {
        $("#temp").html(data.main.temp + "&#176; C");
        units = 'C';
      }
    });
```

Comment: I imagine OP used a delegated event handler for a reason. Why would you change that?

Comment: It works even with the delegated event handler. All good. Should it not work?

Comment: I think omitting all the code from the original post may have confused Phil, the snippet above is intended to be used inside the $.getJSON

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, this

```
if("#temp:contains('&#176; C')")
```

is about as useful as

```
if('any non-empty string')
```

which is equivalent to

```
if(true)
```

---

In any case, I suggest you use a better flag to indicate the temperature scale currently on display. Try using the `.data` API, for example

```
$("#temp").html(data.main.temp + "&#176; C").data('unit', 'C');
```

and in your click handler

```
var temp = $(this); // no need to keep looking this up by ID
switch (temp.data('unit')) {
  case 'F':
    // set temp in C, etc
    temp.data('unit', 'C') // set the unit flag
  case 'C':
  default:
    // set temp in F, etc
    temp.data('unit', 'F') // set the unit flag
}
```